# how to join two table and sum rows by preceded date only

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables

```
--
-- Table structure for table `d_statistics_report_temp`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `d_statistics_report_temp` (
  `srt_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `pub_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `sal_must_pay_date` date DEFAULT NULL ,
  `total_sales` float(7,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_must_pay` float(7,0) NOT NULL,
  `pub_share` float(7,0) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `pub_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ,
  `conversion_doc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`srt_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `d_statistics_report_temp`
--

INSERT INTO `d_statistics_report_temp` 
(`srt_id`, `pub_name`, `sal_must_pay_date`, `total_sales`, `total_must_pay`, `pub_share`, `pub_id`, `conversion_doc`) 
VALUES
(1, 'sara', '2013-03-01', 50, 0, 15, 256, ''),
(2, 'sara', '2013-04-01', 20, 0, 15, 256, ''),
(3, 'sara', '2013-05-01', 80, 0, 15, 256, ''),
(4, 'sara', '2013-06-01', 10, 0, 15, 256, ''),
(5, 'sara', '2013-07-01', 20, 0, 15, 256, ''),
(6, 'sara', '2013-08-01', 70, 0, 15, 256, ''),
(7, 'sara', '2013-09-01', 90, 0, 15, 256, ''),
(8, 'adam', '2013-05-01', 10, 0, 15, 255, '')
```

and the second table

```
--
-- Table structure for table `d_statistics_docs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `d_statistics_docs` (
  `sd_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sd_pub` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sd_date` date NOT NULL,
  `sd_doc` text NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sd_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `d_statistics_docs`
--

INSERT INTO `d_statistics_docs` (`sd_id`, `sd_pub`, `sd_date`, `sd_doc`, `price`) VALUES

(9,  256, '2013-03-01', 'scifiwallpaper1.jpg'),
(10, 256, '2013-04-01', 'scifiwallpaper1.jpg'),
(11, 256, '2013-05-01', ''),
(12, 256, '2013-06-01', 'scifiwallpaper1.jpg'),
(13, 256, '2013-07-01', ''),
(14, 256, '2013-08-01', ''),
(15, 256, '2013-09-01', 'scifiwallpaper1.jpg');
```

i want to join tables to get `total_sales` for every `pub_id` (publisher_id) for every `sd_date`

but i want to put condition `when sd_doc IS NULL` get `total_sales` for this `sd_date` only

and if `sd_doc NOT NULL` return `total_sales` for this month and all months directly preceded

output example

```
9   256     2013-03-01  scifiwallpaper1.jpg 50

10  256     2013-04-01  scifiwallpaper1.jpg 20

11  256     2013-05-01         NULL         80

12  256    2013-06-01   scifiwallpaper1.jpg 90 // total 10 + 80

13  256     2013-07-01         NULL         20

14  256     2013-08-01         NULL        70

15  256     2013-09-01  scifiwallpaper1.jpg 180  // total of 90+70+20
```

***note : sal_must_pay_date = sd_date in the second table***

Comment: I don't understand about the last row in `d_statistics_docs` table. Why the `total_sales` values can be 180. Where it come from ?

Comment: Did you try `SUM(total_sales)`?

Comment: 180 is total for three months 09 + 08+07 .. the point is to check sd_doc if not null sum the direct preceded months only ..not all empty sd_doc  null rows

Comment: i can use sum but the point is the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to track previous rows (as long as you are ordering correctly). So Your query could be written as follows:

```
SET @i = 0.0;

SELECT  rt.srt_id,
        rt.pub_id,
        d.sd_date,
        CASE WHEN d.sd_doc != '' THEN d.sd_doc END sd_doc,
        rt.total_sales,
        @i + rt.total_sales AS Cumulative_Total,
        @i:= CASE WHEN d.sd_doc = '' THEN @i + rt.total_sales ELSE 0 END AS Increment
FROM    d_statistics_report_temp rt
        INNER JOIN d_statistics_docs d
            ON rt.pub_id = d.sd_pub
            AND rt.sal_must_pay_date = d.sd_date
ORDER BY rt.pub_id, d.sd_date;
```

In this case the variable @i alters for each row, resetting to 0 if sd_doc is not blank, or adding to its previous amount if sd_doc is blank.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d326c/7)**